# javascript prototype method returns a string value

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

While learning about object prototypes, I encountered the below example.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
};

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
alert(myFather.name);
```

When I tried to run via browser using html page, the following alert message popped up.

```
function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
}
```

So, instead of returning 'John Doe', it returns the entire function as a string.
How to resolve this?

PS: I use VS Code, and i use node.js live-server to run in browser.

Comment: `alert(myFather.name());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to execute the function by this way `myFather.name()`

```
var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
alert(myFather.name());
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d2hh1ezq/3/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to invoke the function

```
alert(myFather.name());
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the function using `()`

```
myFather.name()
```

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
};

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
console.log(myFather.name());
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a function you are using. Could you use it like `alert(myFather.name());`